# Why is the compiler adding an extra 'sxtw' instruction (resulting further in a kernel panic)?

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, implicit-conversion, function-declaration

Issue/Symptom:

At the end of a function return, the compiler adds an sxtw instruction as seen in the disassembly, resulting in a return address of only 32 bits instead of 64 bits, resulting in a kernel panic:

```
Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address xxxx
```

Build Environment:

Platform : ARMV7LE
  gcc, linux-4.4.60
  Archictecture : arm64
  gdb : aarch64-5.3-glibc-2.22/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gdb

Details:

Here's the simplified project structure. It's been taken care of correctly in the corresponding makefile. Also note that file1.c and file2.c are part of same module.

../src/file1.c /* It has func1() defined as well as called */

  ../src/file2.c

  ../inc/files.h /* There's no func1() declared in the header */

Cause of the issue:

A call to the func1() was added from the file2.c w/o func1 declaration in files.h or file2.c. (Basically the inclusion of func1 was accidentally missed in the files.h.)

Code compiled with no errors, but a warning as expected -- `Implicit declaration of function func1`.

At run time though, right after returning from func1 inside file2, the system crashed as it tried de-referencing the returned address from func1.

Further analysis showed that at the end of a function return, the compiler added an sxtw instruction as seen in the disassembly, resulting in a return address of only 32 bits instead of 64 bits, resulting in a kernel panic.

```
Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address xxxx
```

- Note that x19 is of 64 bit while w0 is of 32 bit.
- Note that x0 LS word matches with that of x19.
- System crashed while de-referencing x19.

sxtw    x19, w0      /* This was added by compiler as extra instruction */
ldp     x1, x0, [x19,#304]    /* System crashed here */

Registers:

```
[   91.388130] pc : [<ffffff80016c9074>] lr : [<ffffff80016c906c>] pstate: 80000145
[   91.462090] sp : ffffff80094333b0
[   91.552708] x29: ffffff80094333d0 x28: ffffffc06995408a
[   91.652701] x27: ffffffc06c400a00 x26: 0000000000000000
[   91.716243] x25: 0000000000000000 x24: ffffffc069958000
[   91.779784] x23: ffffffc076e00000 x22: ffffffc06c400a00
[   91.843326] x21: 0000000000000031 x20: ffffffc073060000
[   91.906867] x19: 0000000066bfc780 x18: ffffff8009436888
[   91.970409] x17: 0000000000000000 x16: ffffff8008193074
[   92.033952] x15: 00000000000a8c06 x14: 2c30323030387830
[   92.097492] x13: 3d7367616c66202c x12: 3038653030303030
[   92.161034] x11: 3038666666666666 x10: 78303d646e65202c
[   92.224576] x9 : 3063303030303030 x8 : 3030303030303030
[   92.288117] x7 : 0000000000000880 x6 : 0000000000000000
[   92.351659] x5 : ffffffc07fd10ad8 x4 : 0000000000000001
[   92.415202] x3 : 0000000000000007 x2 : cb88537fdc8ba63c
[   92.478743] x1 : 0000000000000000 x0 : ffffffc066bfc780
```

After adding the declaration of func1 in the files.h, the extra instruction and hence the crash was *not* seen.

Can someone please explain why the compiler added sxtw in this case?

Comment: Show your compile and link command. You should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). [`SXTW`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0802a/SXTW_SBFM.html) sign extends a 32-bit word to a 64-bit word. Since your platform is ARMv7, I suspect the compiler should not be generating those instructions.

Comment: Please show the declaration of `func1`. What do you mean with "at the end of a function return"? In the code of `func1` before the return or in the caller? If you don't have a prototype for the function the compiler assumes return type `int`. As you wrote about "de-referencing the returned address from func1" I assume the function should return a pointer. I guess `int` is 32 bit and a pointer is 64 bit and the compiler added this instruction because of the wrong implicit declaration as returning `int`.

Answer (score 3):

You should have received at least two warnings, one about the missing function declaration and another one about the the implicit conversion from `int` to a pointer type.

The reason is that implicitly declared functions have a return type of `int`.  Casting this `int` value to a 64-bit pointer throws away 32 bit of the result.  This is the expected GNU C behavior, based on what C compilers for early 64-bit targets did.  The `sxtw` instruction is required to implement this behavior.  (Current C standards no longer have implicit function declarations, but GCC still has to support them for backwards compatibility with existing autoconf tests.)

Note that your platform is obviously Aarch64 (with 64-bit registers), not 32-bit ARMv7.